# Add a mailto button next to custom field download link

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

i created a series of custom feilds that allow uploads of documents to a post and the uploaded documents display as download links on the post page. Now i'm trying to figure out how to add a "mailto button" beside each link so that the  documents can be sent as attachments to a specific  email.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you handling the upload and display of these documents?

Comment: I'm using gravity forms plugin to collect the data and advanced custom fields to display them on a custom post. The uploaded files display as links on the custom post